# how to scroll down small window on web page using python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am doing this..

```
 html = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]')
 html.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

> ERROR=selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException:
> Message: element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

You can try to scroll the element into selenium view :

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Or if you want to vertically scrolldown :

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
```

Y could be `100, 200, and so on...`

or using `ActionChains`

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(html).perform()
```

Comment: A good constrictive answer can be provided by seeing the URL or HTML of web page

Answer (score 0):

You can use
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
where Y is the height (on a fullhd monitor it's 1080).

Comment: try to elaborate your answer.